Why is the count different for cross join in Pyspark w or w/o join condition?
dfj3 = spark.createDataFrame(
    ['a','b','b'],StringType()
    )

dfj4 = spark.createDataFrame(
    ['c','d','e'],StringType()
)

dfj3.join(dfj4).count() // #crossjoin, count = 9
dfj3.join(dfj4,dfj3.value==dfj4.value).count() #innerjoin, count = 0
dfj3.join(dfj4,dfj3.value==dfj4.value,'cross').count() #crossjoin with condition, count = 0

Why is 1st and 3rd cross join working differently?
Expected Cross join with join condition and cross join without join condition should be the same as the joins will be performed for all the records in both tables.

What you expect as a result is like saying SELECT * from table should be the same as SELECT * from table where condition=something. Cross join will create a cartesian product, but since you added a condition, it will filter the results based on your condition and thus give you the empty set, since you don't have any values that are same in those dataframes

All joins are a subset of the mathematical construct called cartesian product - cross join in SQL terms.
So, when you are applying the equality condition on the cross join - it's just behaving like an equi join - a class of inner join - and hence the result is different. This is also mentioned in the Join Wikipedia page:

CROSS JOIN does not itself apply any predicate to filter rows from the joined table. The results of a CROSS JOIN can be filtered using a WHERE clause, which may then produce the equivalent of an inner join.

